# Same variable in two different script tags

Tags: javascript

Here's my first  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    // some code

    var showWarning = true;

    // more code

});
</script>
```

And then I have another script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitFormLink(){
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').action = '<c:url value="/preview-pdf"/>';
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').method = 'POST';
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').submit();
    }
    function submitFormButton(){
        if (showWarning == true){
            alert("hi");
        }
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').action = '';
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').method = 'POST';
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').submit();
    }
 </script>
```

And I get an error saying that showWarning is undefined. I read that variables a global in the same window. So what am I doing wrong herE ?

Comment: You're declaring `var showWarning` *inside* the `$(document).ready(` function.  It's *not* a global variable, it's local to inside that function *only*.

Comment: showWarning is defined in an anonanous function, window cannot see it

Answer (score 5):

You aren't declaring a global.

You are using the `var` keyword inside a function so:

- It won't be defined until the function runs
- It will be local to the function

If you want a global, create the variable in the global scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var showWarning = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // some code
    // more code
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `showWarning` is not global. The scope is the document ready handler. If you want to make it global, you'd have to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var showWarning = true; // now it has global scope

$(document).ready(function () {
    // some code
    // more code
});
</script>
```

Using global variables is considerer a bad practice in javascript so you should avoid doing this every time is possible. For more information about this, look on google for `Pollution of the Global Namespace`

Answer (score 0):

The top variable only exist in the $(document).ready, you'll need to declare it outside of the function:

```
var showWarning;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // some code

     showWarning = true;

    // more code

});
```

Comment: Actually, in this case, the `var showWarning` is redundant. You can take that out completely and it will still be global.

Comment: @meagar — but if you do that, you'll generate an exception in JavaScript's strict mode.

Comment: @Quentin That's why you should explicitly use `window.showWarning = true`. You're going to have to do so later when you access the global variable, so you might as well do so when you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Within the bare `<script>` tags, it would be global:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var showWarning = true;

</script>
```

However, you're inside a function, and you're explicitly scoping the variable to that function with the `var` statement.

If you want to make a *global* variable inside a function, attach it to `window`, which is the global context inside the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    // some code

    window.showWarning = true;

    // more code

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring `showWarning` as a global, you are declaring it inside of a function. If you want to make it a global, you would need to change the definition to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var showWarning = true;
$(document).ready(function () {

    // some code
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're putting ***var*** on javascript, that means local variable. Try removing var on showWarning variable.

```
showWarning = true
```

Comment: `var` only means local when it isn't used at global scope. He could still create a global variable with `var showWarning = true` if he weren't inside a function.